# PHPUnit error in babysteps

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am studying about TDD and I tried to run tests using phpunit in console, but the console return for me the follow error.

> Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\estudos\phpunit\tests\MoneyTest.php on line 8
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\estudos\phpunit\tests\MoneyTest.php on line 8

**How can I solve this ? I am using PSR-4 to create autoloader in this project**

Link from repository with project: https://github.com/alexanderjr/Test-phpunit

Unit test

```
 <?php

require __DIR__.'../../vendor/autoload.php';

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class MoneyTest extends TestCase
{
public function __construct(){

}

public function testCanBeNegated()
{
    // Arrange
    $a = new Money(1);

    // Act
    $b = $a->negate();

    // Assert
    $this->assertEquals(-1, $b->getAmount());
}

}
```

Comment: You need to include the relevant code in your question

Comment: I pasted link from github to see all structure from project, what code that you want to check ? From class of tests ?

Comment: The link is helpful, but clearly you've got one unit test that has problems. So I would post that one test in the question. See [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44440/is-it-okay-to-link-to-gist-code-pastes) for tips on how to do this.

Comment: I pasted in the question the code

Comment: Are you using a version of PHPUnit older than 5.4? `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` is only available as of PHPUnit 5.4, with earlier versions you need to use `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, it works ;)